# ggplot2 - How to replace geom symbol in legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` to plot a time-series graph showing cumulative rainfall for both the current year and the historical values. I am also adding a couple of vertical lines in the graph indicating phonological stages of my interest. Therefore, I need two legends: one for rainfall and one for phenology.

Here is what I have so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Set random seed
set.seed(83)

# generate data frames
df1 <- data.frame(jday=1:365,
                  value=runif(n=365, min=3, max=10)-3,
                  type="current")
df1$csum <- cumsum(df1$value)

df2 <- data.frame(jday=1:365,
                  value=runif(n=365, min=0, max=10),
                  type="historical")
df2$csum <- cumsum(df2$value)

# plot data
ggplot() +
  geom_line(df1, mapping=aes(x=as.Date(jday, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), y=csum, fill=type), colour="steelblue3") +
  geom_ribbon(df2, mapping=aes(x=as.Date(jday, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), ymin=0, ymax=csum, fill=type), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(150, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Planting"), linetype="longdash") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(180, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Germination"), linetype="longdash") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(210, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Flowering"), linetype="longdash") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(240, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Grain filling"), linetype="longdash") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(270, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Maturity"), linetype="longdash") +
  theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="15 days", date_labels="%d/%b/%y") +
  labs(y="Cumulative rainfall (mm)", x= "Date") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Phenological stages",
                     breaks=c("Planting","Germination","Flowering","Grain filling","Maturity"),
                     values = c("Planting" = "#24CF09",
                                "Germination" = "#49A012",
                                "Flowering" = "#5B8817",
                                "Grain filling" = "#805920",
                                "Maturity" = "#A52A2A")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title=element_text(size=18),
        legend.text = element_text(size=18)) +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=FALSE,
                             title.position="top", title.hjust=0.5)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=FALSE,
                           title.position="top", title.hjust=0.5)) +
scale_fill_manual(name="Rainfall",
                  values=c("current"="steelblue3", "historical"="skyblue1"),
                  labels=c("current"="Current year", "historical"="Historical"),
                  breaks=c("current","historical"))
```

[image]

The plot itself yields what I wanted, but there is a little detail that I **really** need to change. In the legend named `Rainfall`, I need to replace the `Current year` symbol from a "fill" to a "line", in order to match the `geom_line` that is being used in the plot.

However, I can't seem to find an easy (i.e. documented) way to do that. Any hints on how to get there? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A second approach to get the desired result would be to make use of a custom `key_glyph` which uses the default rect glyph for the `fill` legend in case of the historical data and and a `line` or `path` glyph for the current data.

My custom glyph function is simply a wrapper which depending on the `type` or actually the `fill` color (see the note) calls `ggplot2::draw_key_rect` or `ggplot2::draw_key_path`.

**Note 1** To the best of my knowledge it's not possible to condition on `type`. Instead we have to condition on the assigned `fill` color, i.e. we have to do `if (data$fill == "skyblue1")` to check for `type == "historical"`.

**Note 2** As `draw_key_path` needs a `color` instead of a `fill` we have to manually adjust the values for color aesthetic. This could be achieved in two ways.

1. You could "hardcode" the values inside the custom function or
2. You could adjust the values of aes via `guides(..., override.aes = ...)`

My edited code makes use of the second approach. Additionally I set the `alpha=1` for the line and adjusted the `size`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Custom key glyph
draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (data$fill == "skyblue1") {
    draw_key_rect(data, params, size)
  } else {
    # Hard code the values or make use of guides(..., override.aes(...)) (see below)
    # data$colour <- data$fill
    # data$alpha <- 1
    draw_key_path(data, params, size)
  }
}

# plot data
ggplot() +
  geom_line(df1, mapping = aes(x = as.Date(jday, origin = as.Date("2020-01-01")), y = csum, fill = "current"), colour = "steelblue3", key_glyph = "cust") +
  geom_ribbon(df2, mapping = aes(x = as.Date(jday, origin = as.Date("2020-01-01")), ymin = 0, ymax = csum, fill = "historical"), alpha = 0.5, key_glyph = "cust") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.Date(150, origin = as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour = "Planting"), linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.Date(180, origin = as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour = "Germination"), linetype = "longdash") +
  # geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(210, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Flowering"), linetype="longdash") +
  # geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(240, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Grain filling"), linetype="longdash") +
  # geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(270, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Maturity"), linetype="longdash") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "15 days", date_labels = "%d/%b/%y") +
  labs(y = "Cumulative rainfall (mm)", x = "Date") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Phenological stages",
    breaks = c("Planting", "Germination", "Flowering", "Grain filling", "Maturity"),
    values = c(
      "Planting" = "#24CF09",
      "Germination" = "#49A012",
      "Flowering" = "#5B8817",
      "Grain filling" = "#805920",
      "Maturity" = "#A52A2A"
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    # legend.title=element_text(size=18),
    # legend.text = element_text(size=18)
  ) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(
    nrow = 1, byrow = FALSE,
    title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5
  )) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(
    nrow = 1, byrow = FALSE,
    title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5,
    # Use override.aes to set the aes prams for the glyph
    override.aes = list(color = c("steelblue3", NA), size = c(2, .5), alpha = c(1, .5))
  )) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "Rainfall",
    values = c("current" = "steelblue3", "historical" = "skyblue1"),
    labels = c("current" = "Current year", "historical" = "Historical"),
    breaks = c("current", "historical")
  )
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, it works great and does not need an extra package. However, I was unable to find a way to increase the size (thickness) of the "Current year" line in the legend. Would that be possible in your solution?

Comment: Good morning Thiago. Of course is this possible. I just made an edit. And additionally improved the code a bit. Instead of copy and pasting the code from `draw_key_xxx` I simply call the default functions depending on the condition. Best S.

Comment: Very nice! It works as intended and is very close to what I was doing originally. I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a couple of approaches with `ggnewscale::new_scale_color`:

```
library(ggnewscale)
ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(df2, mapping=aes(x=as.Date(jday, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), ymin=0, ymax=csum, fill=type), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(274, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Planting"), linetype="longdash") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(309, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Flowering"), linetype="longdash") +
  theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="15 days", date_labels="%d/%b/%y") +
  labs(y="Cumulative rainfall (mm)", x= "Date") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Phenological stages",
                     breaks=c("Planting","Flowering"),
                     values = c("Planting" = "#24CF09",
                                "Flowering" = "#805920"),
                     guide=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=FALSE,
                            override.aes = list(fill = "black"),
                            title.position="top", title.hjust=0.5)) +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(df1, mapping=aes(x=as.Date(jday, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), y=csum, colour="current")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Rainfall", 
                     values=c("current"="steelblue3", "historical" = "skyblue1"),
                     labels = c("current"="Current year","historical"="Historical"),
                     drop = FALSE,
                     guide=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=FALSE,
                                        override.aes = list(fill = "black"),
                                        title.position="top", title.hjust=1.4)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values=c("current"="steelblue3", "historical" = "skyblue1"),
                    labels = c("current"="Current year","historical"="Historical"),
                    drop = FALSE,
                    guide = guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=FALSE,
                                         title.position="top", title.hjust=0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title=element_text(size=18),
        legend.text = element_text(size=18))
```

[image]

```
ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(df2, mapping=aes(x=as.Date(jday, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), ymin=0, ymax=csum, fill=type), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(274, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Planting"), linetype="longdash") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.Date(309, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), colour="Flowering"), linetype="longdash") +
  theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="15 days", date_labels="%d/%b/%y") +
  labs(y="Cumulative rainfall (mm)", x= "Date") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Phenological stages",
                     breaks=c("Planting","Flowering"),
                     values = c("Planting" = "#24CF09",
                                "Flowering" = "#805920"),
                     guide=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=FALSE,
                            override.aes = list(fill = "black"),
                            title.position="top", title.hjust=0.5)) +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(df1, mapping=aes(x=as.Date(jday, origin=as.Date("2020-01-01")), y=csum, colour="current")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Rainfall", 
                     values=c("current"="steelblue3", "historical" = "skyblue1"),
                     labels = c("current"="Current year","historical"="Historical"),
                     drop = FALSE,
                     guide=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=FALSE,
                                        override.aes = list(fill = "black"),
                                        title.position="bottom", title.hjust=0.4)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Rainfall", values=c("current"="steelblue3", "historical" = "skyblue1"),
                    labels = c("current"="Current year","historical"="Historical"),
                    drop = FALSE,
                    guide = guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=FALSE,
                                         title.position="bottom", title.hjust=0.65)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title=element_text(size=18),
        legend.text = element_text(size=18))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe worth to point out that the trick is *also* to change the slightly erroneous fill aesthetic in geom_line to color

Comment: I suspect the fill aesthetic was purposeful on the question author's part. It was a stock ggplot hack to create a kind of second color legend.

Comment: @IanCampbell, thank you a lot for the answer! It works perfectly for the provided example, but my real data has more phenological stages. In that case, the legend for the phenological stages stays right in between the ones for rainfall - please see the edited question. Do you happen to know any way to fix it? Thanks again!

Comment: @thiagoveloso I'm not sure I follow. Both approaches seem to work for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3DET.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xkie.png